How to send email with attachment using brevo api
I am using brevo API and trying to send the base64 string as an attachment I am able to receive the email but not the attachment
Here is my sample code
var emailData = new
{
    sender = new { email = smtpSettings.FromEmail, name = smtpSettings.FromName },
    to = toAddresses,
    subject = "Timesheet Submission for Review",
    htmlContent = modified,
    attachments = new []
    {
        new { content = base64File, name = "Text.xlsx", type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" }
    }

};
string jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailData);

using var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", smtpSettings.ApiKey);

var response = await client.PostAsync(smtpSettings.ApiUrl, new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;


Is the file oversized, according to the doc, accept type is needed. Could test with the template to check the result to compare.

No it is just a sample excel file. I am able to do it using SendSmtpEmail but not with API directly not sure what was the issue

The official sample is "attachment":[{"url":"https://attachment.domain.com/myAttachmentFromUrl.jpg","content":"b3JkZXIucGRm","name":"myAttachment.png"}], you could check this format.

Thanks it worked, url is not mandatory
